# Fastest way to find multiples in an unordered list

Tags: python, list

Part of a challenge requires that I find multiples of a number in an unordered list. For instance:

Given **3** and **[6,7,8,2,12,6]**: I want **[6,12,6]** because 6 and 12 are multiples of 3. The lists and integers will obviously be appreciably bigger, and duplicates and order matters.

---

I was originally doing this with a list comprehension, where I would check every element for whether or not it was a multiple:

```
x = 3 
list = [6,7,8,2,12,6]

multiples = [y for y in list if y % x == 0]
```

but the challenge's execution time limit didn't like this, and my assumption was that the modulo operation was taking a while when iterating through large lists.

---

My next idea which was much quicker (or so I thought) was an intersection of two lists:

1. The given (unordered) list
2. A set of all multiples for **x** between **x** and the largest value in the unordered list (1.)

intuition told me:

```
x = 3 
list = [6,7,8,2,12,6]

multiples = set(xrange(x,max(list),x)).intersection(list)
```

but it seems like duplicates in `intersection()` aren't preserved.

---

Is there any way to improve the speed of the first one, or preserve duplicates in the second one? Or is there some tertiary way of doing this that's much better? Thanks.

Comment: Just a helping note: it's not that duplicates in `intersection()` aren't preserved, they were lost in the moment you created a `set`.

Comment: What you have is fine. But, if you are given a long list of numbers and another list of numbers to find the corresponding multiples, you can preprocess the long list by factorizing the numbers and storing them.

Comment: Which challenge is this? The time limit is imposed for what hardware?

Comment: What challenge so we can test to see if our answer is correct.

Comment: Maybe `s=set(range(x, max(list),x))` `[y for y in l if y in s]`

Comment: You can shave a couple of percent with `[y for y in list if not y % x]`

Comment: @lucasnadalutti Yeah, my naive brain thought that only the `xrange` would become a set. It's my first programming rodeo.

@thefourtheye I had never thought of that, I'm going to give that a shot

@Ukimiku The challenge asks that I find the number of occurrences in a given list where 3 numbers are multiples of each other: C is a multiple of B is a multiple of A. The hardware is sufficiently quick judging from earlier challenges, but I don't know exactly what it is and I can't print any profiles in the command line.

Comment: `max(list)` will be `O(n)`, just like your original list comprehension. The modulus operation should be about as fast as anything else that operates on each element, including finding the max. I can't really think of a solution that will be much faster.